# Is this domain a second-level domain name?

Tags: dns, subdomain

```
bbs.example.com
```

I referred to the domain name knowledge on Wikipedia, and have read through the page, but I still don't know what is a second-level domain name? The page says `com` is a TLD (Top Level Domain), and the TLDs are the highest level of domain names on the Internet.

It says. `bbs.example.com` is a third-level domain name?  But someone told me `bbs.example.com` is a second-level domain name. `.com` is the TLD, not the domain name.

Which is right? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bbs` in `bbs.example.com` is a third-level domain name. `example` in `example.com` is a second-level domain name. `com` is a top-level domain name. (TLD)

Comment: what's the difference between the domain name and domain? are they the same thing?

Answer (score 5):

My answer is maybe too late, but I wanted to add some details to @icktoofay's correct answer.

The Domain Name System is a hierarchical naming system (tree). The hierarchy is represented by each part separated by a dot, that are interpreted from right to left for example: `bbs.example.com.` should be interpreted as `.com.example.bbs` and decomposed as:

- Layer 1: `.com` is a Top Level Domain
- Layer 2:`.com.example` is a Second Level Domain
- Layer 3:`.com.example.bbs` is a Third Level Domain

That's where the notion of top, second and third level are coming from.

I wrote an article on my personal blog introducing the domain name system if you are interested where I describe this in more detail: [What's a domain name and what's behind the scene](https://web.archive.org/web/20131006020635/http://anouar.im/2011/12/what-is-a-domain-name-and-what-is-behind-the-scene.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the separate list of tlds from https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

This is maintained by mozilla.

By using this list of tld you can find the domain level.

Let me know if you have any more queries.