# Regex to extract the top level domain from a URL

Tags: regex, url

I want to extract the top level domain from a URL:
The logs are like this:

```
<182>Jul 28 13:52:34 PROXYSQUID1 logger: 1501249953.155      0 192.168.4.27 TCP_MISS/503 2408 POST http://xxxxx.ddns.net:xxx/xxxxx - DIRECT/xxx.xx.x.xx text/html
```

I want to get only the top level domain:

```
ddns
```

I tried this regex

```
([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.])
```

But I got

```
xxxxx.ddns
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You kind of mistook the words here... A TLD (Top Level Domain) refers to the last segment of a domain name or the part that follows immediately after the "dot" symbol. (E.g.: `.com`, `.net`, etc..)

What you're searching for is the [second level domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6555572/7225971) (or SLD).

I've edited **[Daveo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/7225971)** for your question, so the match will be returned to the first capture group:

```
(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+~.#=]{2,256}\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+~#=]*)\.[a-z]{2,6}\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)
```

Here is a demo: https://regex101.com/r/x2luiO/1

**Explanation:**

- `(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+~.#=]{2,256}\.)?` - This first part will get everything before your SLD (subdomains).
- `([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+~#=]*)` - This is your capturing group (Where the domain should be returned)
- `\.[a-z]{2,6}` - This will match the TLD (if you also want to capture)
- `\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)` - And this is the rest of the regex, that should match the port and/or the rest of the URL (`/example/page/`).

It's also good to point that this regex will not match if you're testing a domain with the SLD and ccTLD (Country Code TLD) 'combo', example: `.co.uk` and `.co.it`, both are just the end of a domain for commercial and general websites, however, both will return `co` as the SLD.

Comment: This fails in a ton of cases.